# Why does Speedo On app does not show on Galaxy Store?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-gear

I have a Samsung Galaxy Gear Fit2 Pro and a Samsung Galaxy Note9. I installed the [Speedo On](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedo) app on the phone, which requires a companion Speedo On app from the Galaxy Store for the watch.

> Samsung - If you have a Samsung Gear Fit2 Pro watch or a Samsung Gear watch, please ensure that the Speedo On app is installed on both your smartphone and your watch. To download the watch app: Select “Settings”, Select “Samsung Galaxy apps”, Search “Speedo On”, Select “Install”

However, when I search for this app in the Galaxy Store, it does not show up in the results.

I called Speedo and they assured that the device is supported and I saw reviews in the App Store with people saying they are using it the Fit2 Pro.

Does anyone have this issue? Is there a way to side-load the app to the watch?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I added the description from the Play Store since I assume that's what you did but failed, or perhaps I misunderstood that you did a different thing? (Not from "Settings" but from "Galaxy Store"?) If my edit made this question nonsensical, feel free to rollback!

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, that's what I did. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Samsung and they said this app is not supported on the Gear Fit2 Pro.